# « un peu de plus », « un peu de moins »

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, france

**La Petite Fadette**, George Sand

> – Mais, Fadette, tu n’es pas si vilaine que tu le
> crois, ou que tu veux bien le dire. Il y en a de
> bien plus déplaisantes que toi à qui l’on n’en fait
> pas reproche.
> – Que je le sois un peu de plus, un peu de
> moins, tu ne peux pas dire, Landry, que je suis
> une jolie fille.

Il me semble que l'on ne doit pas dire « un peu de plus », « un peu de moins » pour lesquels il existe « un peu plus » et « un peu moins » ;

Il existe un autre sens de « un peu de plus » qu'une
recherche Google montre appartenir au parler Poitevin ([dictionnaire](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Dictionnaire_encyclop%C3%A9dique_illustr%C3%A9_d/Z7ufEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22un+peu+de+plus%22&pg=PA199&printsec=frontcover)) ; ce sens c'est « il s'en est fallu de peu pour que ». Il me semble que ce n'est pas restreint au Poitou et  ça s'entend dans le parler d'autres régions. Ça correspond à « un peu plus (et) » ([TlFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/peu), Un peu plus* (et) + verbe à l'ind. imp. ou au cond. [Pour indiquer que qqc. est ou a été sur le point de se réaliser]). Est-ce que lorsque la locution a ce second sens elle serait ou deviendrait acceptable, au moins dans le parler ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Une peu de plus* n'est pas très courant, mais se rencontre.

> Le nombre de chômeurs sans activité a diminué **d'un peu de plus** de 14.000 en moyenne de janvier à mars en France entière, hors Mayotte, pour atteindre 3,8 millions.
>
> [Les Echos, avril 2021](https://www.lesechos.fr/economie-france/social/leger-inflechissement-du-chomage-au-premier-trimestre-en-france-1310281)

> J'ai pris **un peu de plus** de force, je le constate sur un parcours tout plat où on a parfois eu le vent dans le dos.
>
> Juliette Labous, [L'Équipe, septembre 2021](https://www.lequipe.fr/Cyclisme-sur-route/Actualites/Juliette-labous-6e-du-contre-la-montre-des-championnats-du-monde-c-est-ma-meilleure-performance/1286821)

> Par ailleurs, les multipropriétaires sont concentrés parmi les plus hauts revenus. 34% des ménages possèdent un logement, ce qui représente au total **un peu de plus** de 34% des logements détenus par les ménages.
>
> [Vie publique, décembre 2021](https://www.vie-publique.fr/en-bref/282679-logement-forte-concentration-de-la-propriete-immobiliere)

Comment: Ça me parait lourd. Comme les références sont trouvées dans la presse, il s'agirait peut-être de langue populaire ou régionale (plusieurs régions) ?

Comment: Je viens de rajouter une occurrence qui provient d'un site institutionnel.